# Sources on Several Complex Variables

Tags: reference-request, complex-analysis, several-complex-variables

I have searched the past entries about sources on SCV but couldn't find about this topic. If I am not careful enough, sorry for this!

We are using Hörmander's book which is really hard to follow. What do you suggest?
Besides textbooks, it's welcome if you suggest manuscripts, lecture notes etc.

Thank you!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There's an MIT OCW package from 2005 for a course in several complex variables available [here](http://ocw.mit.edu/courses/mathematics/18-117-topics-in-several-complex-variables-spring-2005/).

Also, there's a "sketch" of a course given at MIT in 2004 available [here](http://www.dms.umontreal.ca/~gauthier/6140.pdf).

Lastly, of course there's always this site, where many very smart people are more than happy to help with focused questions! :)

Comment: And the MIT course was taught by none other than... Victor Guillemin!

Answer (score 3):

Krantz's book is quite nice.   [Here](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0821827243) is a link to it.

Answer (score 3):

Range's book Holomorphic Functions and Integral Representations in Several Complex Variables is very nice! See [this](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/1441930787)